# Changing user agent is possible for Page Inspector?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I didn't use page inspector much. 
After seeing they made [some improvements](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/14/announcing-the-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-release-candidate.aspx) like runtime CSS change synch with CSS files i though it might be a good idea to give it a shot.

But i should change user agent as a mobile user agent. I can do it with any browser.

Does page inspector has any options about changing user agents ?

PS: I'm currently working with asp.net-mvc4.